# copying dictionary doesn't give me expected result

Tags: c#, dictionary, copy

I have to copy one dictionary, work with that copy and return to the original one.

What seems to happen is that the orignal dictionary is modified when I do some work on the copied one.

Here is my code :

```
dmodified_profile = new SortedDictionary<int,SortedDictionary<string,List<string>>>(d_profile);
```

I don't know why d_profile which is the original one could be modified if my modifications are done on the dmodified_profile dictionary ?

Thanks

Comment: You might consider investigating using an immutable data structure. They are highly amenable to the sort of operation you're talking about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to [deep copy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-an-object-in-net-c-specifically).

Answer (score 3):

Your SortedDictionary maps an integer to a REFERENCE to another SortedDictionary. When you copy that dictionary you copy the values of the keys as well as the REFERENCEs of the values, because your dictionary's value is of a reference type.